# What does xchg eax, eax do? Is it a NOP?

Tags: assembly, x86, swap, no-op

What is the effect of:

```
xchgl %eax, %eax
```

`xchg` is for swapping data, but if src and dst are the same, then it has basically no effect?

Comment: What's the binary value of that instruction?

Comment: I don't really know, I saw the example in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer for data swap

Comment: One possible encoding of that instruction is `0x90` which is also known as a `NOP`. So yeah, it doesn't have any effect. Note however in 64 bit mode it does have a side effect of zeroing the upper 32 bits (this fact is used by compilers).

Comment: @teaLeef: I also didn't know. While my PDF viewer was loading the Intel manual, I ran the instruction through an assembler followed by `objdump`, and lo! and behold, it said `0:   90     nop`...

Comment: @Jester actually 0x90 `nop` is a special case in x86_64 because it won't zero out the top bits like other instructions https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/816755/ml64-assembles-xchg-eax-eax-instruction-incorrectly "Hopefully, 90 is truly a nop, even in 64 bits." https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/x86oddities#nop

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes the 0x90 nop doesn't. But `xchg eax, eax` won't be assembled to 0x90 in 64 bit mode and will clear the top bits. Ah, I see you know that too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xchg eax, eax`, or in binary the one-byte instruction `0x90`, is also known as `nop`. It does nothing.

Comment: there is another 2-byte encoding for `xchg eax, eax` which isn't a nop on x86_64: `87c0`

Comment: So what is this encoding for?

Comment: Very few people know that xchg eax, eax is equivalent to nop! @teaLeef: A nop generally is used to waste a defined number of clock cycles.

Comment: @carveone: A `nop` instruction is very useful for establishing code jump target alignment, patchability, etc.